# Consonant gemination and stress patterns

Tags: phonology, linguistic-typology, stress

Is there a strong correlation between geminate consonants and initial-syllable stress, or stress in the earlier syllables of words?

A survey of European languages suggests that there might be such a correlation. For example, in Italian, where antepenultimate stress is common, geminate consonants are ubiquitous (*fatto* "done", *troppo* "too much", etc.). By contrast, geminates seem rare-to-absent in standard Spanish/Portuguese (which have more thoroughgoing penultimate/final stress) and French (which has mainly final stress).

Similarly, most Germanic languages had geminates at some point in their history (although many are no longer true phonetic geminates due to sound change), and initial-syllable stress was historically the norm in Germanic. Cf. English *tap* < Old Eng. *tæppa*, Icelandic *tappi* "cork, peg", German *Zapfen* "peg, pin", etc.

Thanks for any further insight into this issue.

Comment: Antepenultimate stress is not "the norm" in Italian.

Comment: Interesting theme for a survey study. I browsed the WALS survey (see http://wals.info/chapter ) and found a survey of stress patterns (§14), but no survey of geminate consonants.

Comment: @fdb Fair enough, I changed "the norm" to "common".

Comment: A further objection: You cannot claim that "most Germanic languages had geminates at some point in their history" without admitting that all Romance languages also had geminates "at some point in their history", namely in Latin.

Comment: @fdb I don't see a conflict. In both Romance and Germanic, those languages that remain closer to the earlier stress pattern (word-initial in the case of Germanic, antepenultimate in Romance) seem to have more of a tendency to retain geminates.

Comment: See 'Verschärfung" -- a doubling of glides in "strong" syllables.

Comment: Antepenultimate stress is hardly "stress in the earlier syllables of words" -- if anything, it's stress in the later syllables, because it's counted from the end, not the beginning. It's a real stretch to lump it in with initial stress as some kind of unitary category.

Comment: Antepenultimate stress is earlier than penultimate or final, and it frequently translates into initial stress if a language has few tetrasyllabic or longer words.

Comment: a possible counter-example is Arabic, where gemination occurs everywhere including across word boundaries.

Comment: ps that means gemination can and does occur on the initial consonant.

Comment: "Antepenultimate in Romance" isn't really an "earlier stress pattern", since Latin words could be stressed on the penult or the antepenult (probably more often the former). Most Italian words have penultimate stress; even if the percentage of antepenult-stressed words in Italian is somewhat greater than in Spanish, it doesn't seem like a very significant difference. Another counterexample is Biblical Hebrew, which has geminates and (mostly) final stress.

Comment: @TKR On what basis can we pronounce the difference insignificant? At least the many 3pl. verb forms with the added vowel *-o* (*seguono, mangiano*, etc.) seem to add up to quite a lot. Although this *-o* was not present in Latin, the fact that Italian retains more unstressed syllables does make it closer to the Latin stress pattern (including that of earlier Latin, which is thought to have had word-initial stress) than Spanish/etc.

Comment: OK, but that *-o* is an innovation vis-a-vis Latin, and Latin had geminates, so if the verb forms in *-o* are the main reason to count Italian as having "early accent" then Latin becomes a counterexample to the suggested correlation. More generally, if you're positing a correlation between X and Y you need to define X and Y clearly. X is having geminates, but Y seems to include "initial stress" as well as "antepenultimate stress in some percentage of words larger than that of Spanish", which doesn't look like a meaningful category.

Comment: And either Italian is close to the stress pattern of earlier Latin (which it's not, because it doesn't have initial stress) or it's close to the stress pattern of Classical Latin (in which penultimate stress is at least as common as antepenultimate).

Comment: @TKR I don't see why it cannot be close to both. The fact that Italian does not have initial stress everywhere doesn't take away from the fact that a large percentage of its vocabulary is initially stressed.

Comment: The early Latin (or rather pre-Latin) stress rule was that all words had fixed initial stress. It's not a statistical issue -- it's a phonological rule that Italian lacks. In any case, I think a better way to approach this question would be to ask whether languages that have fixed initial stress are more likely than others to allow geminates. I'm still not sure if a "yes" answer would be of any particular signifiance, but that way at least the categories are well defined.

Comment: @TKR OK, so this hinges on the question of whether phonological rules exist independently of statistical momentum. I am not at all convinced that they do (or at least as commonly as they are claimed to), but I don't want to debate the question here.

Answer (score 2):

Let us stick with Italian and Spanish. Both of these have retained (broadly speaking) the position of the Latin accent. Italian has also retained Latin geminate consonants, as well as creating new geminates through the simplification of clusters (type: factum > fatto). Spanish, on the other hand, has lost all Latin geminates except for -rr-. So the two languages agree (mainly) with regards to the accent, but diverge with regards to geminates. This speaks loudly against the notion of a correlation between accent and gemination.

Comment: Maybe there is no correlation, but I don't think the case can be declared closed so quickly. It seems to me that Italian has significantly more antepenultimate-stressed words than Spanish, because 1) Italian has retained unstressed syllables that Spanish has deleted (It. *popolo* vs. Sp. *pueblo*, It. *chiedere* vs. Sp. *querer*), and 2) it has added final vowels that Spanish has not (It. *chiedono* vs. Sp. *quieren*).

Comment: @user8017, It is possible that there are more apu-stressed words in Italian than in Spanish. My point is that both pópolo and puéblo have retained the stress on the same syllable as pópulus. The position of the stress is determined by etymology, not by the phonological environment. Where the place of the stress differs, as in chiédere vs querér, this has a morphological rather than a phonological rationale (in this case: merger of the 2nd and 3rd conjugation).

Answer (score 1):

There is a well-known indirect correlation between stress and gemination, because (1) heavy syllables tend to attract stress and (2) geminate consonants tend to make syllables heavy. The former correlation is frequently referred to as the Weight-to-Stress principle. The correlation between stress and syllable weight is so strong that it is used presumptively to establish the subtypology of syllable weight, where long vowels always make a syllable heavy, and coda consonants may. In moraic theory, it is generally held that autonomous coda consonants (part of a two-consonant cluster) may have an additional mora (long vowels always do), but the first half of a geminate always does. The pattern where geminates attract stress, while other CC clusters do not, turns out to be rather rare, appearing in Cahuilla, San`ani Yemeni Arabic, some dialects of Hindi and Pattani Malay (the latter, though, is quite bizarre since usually onset geminates do not cause syllables to behave as though they are heavy). Post-hoc analysis of the possibilities for stress and syllable weight correlation, in light of these factors that influence stress, actually reveals that geminate consonants tend to be treated exactly the same as autonomous CC clusters, so that geminates are not usually special, although there are a few languages where they are.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not seeing how this bears on the question, which seems to be whether a language's having geminates at all is correlated with initial stress (not whether geminates attract stress). I also don't understand this sentence: "The correlation between stress and syllable weight is so strong that it is used presumptively to establish the subtypology of syllable weight, where long vowels always make a syllable heavy, and coda consonants may." Where does stress, as opposed to vowel length, come into the typology?

Comment: The question is unclear as to what is really at stake. If for example the question were "Does having word-initial stress cause gemination", then the answer is "no". There is a strong correlation between gemination and "early stress" -- rightward-looking stress rules are often stopped at a geminate. To the extent that stress is rule-governed, facts that govern stress attraction are relevant to where stress is. So certainly there is a construal of the question that is disfavorable to my answer. I didn't write the question, and it is unclear what the OP is really asking.

Comment: Fair enough. @user8017, are you asking whether the location of stress is related to the location of a geminate in a word, or whether the linguistic characters "language X has geminates" and "language X has initial/early stress" are correlated?